# How to get a name out of a String in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a div element with the following html content:

```
<div id="status">
    Welcome, bob!
</div>
```

In my client side javascript file, I want to get the name bob in a variable:

```
var myName = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
```

Thus removing the first string **Welcome,** and the last character **!**, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could just `.slice`, if its always going to be "Welcome, name!".

Comment: if you are generating this code yourself you could make things easier by adding the name to the `div`-tag and grab it from there. Like `data-name=bob` or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `.slice` (simple, probably preferred, method):

If it is always going to be "Welcome, name!", you could use `.slice`:

```
var text = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML.trim();
var myName = text.slice(9, -1);

// myName === "bob"
```

This works with other names too.

```
<div id="status">
  Welcome, Jamen!
</div>
```

Would result in `myName` being `"Jamen"`.

---

## Using `data-*` attributes:

As [RST](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2332721/rst) elaborated, you could setup your HTML to make this a lot more simple, if it is yours.

```
<div id="status" data-name="Jamen">
  Welcome, Jamen!
</div>
```

With:

```
var myName = document.getElementById("status").getAttribute("data-name");
```

---

## Using data-binding libraries:

As a big alternative, you could consider a library that does data-binding.  For instance, here is an example using [VueJS](http://vuejs.org/):

```
<div id="status">
  Welcome, {{name}}!
</div>
```

Then we can use:

```
var status = new Vue({
  el: '#status',
  data: { name: 'Jamen' }
});

// status.name === "Jamen"
```

Of course, this is probably more than necessary for just this question, since data-binding libraries do a lot more than let you access values in HTML, but it's just a thought if you're doing more beyond what you posted in this question.

Comment: Yes the pattern will remain the same, thanks this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to commit to Welcome you can define

```
function GetLastWordWithoutLastChar(text) {
    var words = text.split(" ");
    return words[words.length - 1].slice(0, -1);
}
```

and then use

```
var statusElement = document.getElementById("status");
var myName = GetLastWordWithoutLastChar(statusElement.innerHTML);
```